# What happens to pointer that belongs to object whos copy was pushed to vector?

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, vector, copy

I'm using Qt/C++.

So I have a vector :

```
QVector<Room> rooms; //does everything like normal vector from what I've seen(I hope)
```

My room class looks something like this :

```
class Room{
  Textbox *t;
  //other stuff
}
```

When room is added, vector makes a copy of the room passed by reference and pushes copy in :

```
void Floor::AddRoom(Room &_room, QWidget *_window)
{
  rooms.push_back(_room);    
}
```

My question is what will happen to Textbox pointer that belongs to `_room` since it is pointing at something before copy if it is made? Will my new pushed room had it's `*t` pointing to the same address/object as `_room` that was passed by reference or will it became nullptr?

I read documentation but couldn't find anything about what happens to pointers when copy of object is pushed to vector.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Congratulations, you've just come across a fundamental problem is software design: ownership of data. Google "C++ smart pointers".

Comment: This is *trivial* to answer with a debugger, or for that matter a single print to stdout of both the inbound `_room` argument's pointer and the back of the vector's object's pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's going to point to the same object as originally if you don't provide your own copy constructor, because the value of the pointer is copied, not the object the pointer points to.